# How to use `prepare(_ context: CGContext, with rendererContext: UIGraphicsRendererContext)`?

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, uigraphicsrenderer

Starting iOS 10, Apple documents this class function in UIKit:

[`class func prepare(_ context: CGContext, 
              with rendererContext: UIGraphicsRendererContext)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsrenderer/1649837-prepare)

However, I was not able to access `prepare` in Xcode 8.3.3:

```
// error: Type 'UIGraphicsRenderer' has no member 'prepare'
UIGraphicsRenderer.prepare(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!, with: UIGraphicsRendererContext())

// error: Type 'UIGraphicsImageRenderer' has no member 'prepare'
UIGraphicsImageRenderer.prepare(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!, with: UIGraphicsRendererContext())
```

Comment: You have to import ````import UIKit.UIGraphicsRendererSubclass````, the method is defined in this class.

Comment: you're welcome, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function prepare is defined in `UIGraphicsRendererSubclass`
You can import this class with calling`import UIKit.UIGraphicsRendererSubclass`